# How to convert all color code #XXYYZZ to shorter 3 character version #XYZ of whole css file?

Tags: css, colors, shorthand

How to convert all color code #XXYYZZ to shorter 3 character version #XYZ of whole css file?

Comment: Hint: If your title and your question is the same, either the title is too long or the question is too short. In this case probably both; it seems like you want to do this in some kind of automated way, but what did you have in mind?

Comment: Jitendra - You ask a lot of questions about anything, don't you? Do you really ask because you're wondering, because you want rep, or because you need people to tell you every step of whatever it is you do at any time?

Comment: i ask anything if it useful for others, if I know but want to know others/more view, If something i don't know, if anything new comes in my mind and related to SO, if any of my friend and student asks me. - Isn't good to ask more question? I'm not here for rep but to increase knowledge

Comment: It's just that most of your questions have a solution if you take 10 seconds to google it before asking. And half of them are so simple that they should be taught in the introductory course of the technology in question.

Comment: @Mark Byers. This won't loose any precision. #aabbcc is exactly the same as #abc. Now if you were rounding off the last character, (#b9e809 -> #be0) then you would have a loss of precision. I assume they want to know this to compress the files.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: I see... Jitendra only wants to perform this operation when it *doesn't* cause loss of precision, not for all color codes in the CSS. I misread the question.

Comment: @Tor Valamo - you mean if i can find a solution in google than problem should not be asked on SO and same for introductory question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert to the shorter 3-character version only colors expressed this way: #RRGGBB where the first and the second characters are the same, the third and fourth characters are the same and the fifth and sixth characters are the same.

So: `#CC00DD` can be shortened to `#C0D` while `#CC01DD` cannot.

A quick way to shorten all the possible colors in a CSS file is to open the file with an editor supporting regular expressions (for example kwrite or kate on linux) and replace (ignoring case) the following regular expression:

`#([0-9A-F])\1([0-9A-F])\2([0-9A-F])\3`

with this substitution text:

`#\1\2\3`

Tested with kate.

Otherwise you can use [this tool](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressoradvanced/) where, if you only need to compress color codes, you can uncheck all the options except the "Compress color codes where possible".

Answer (score 3):

If you are just interested in minimizing the download size for your CSS file, you might use one of the many CSS compressors available (such as [this](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/) one). And be sure to do the same with your javascript files while you are at it.

Comment: +1 that's the only right way to do it. Everything else is just useless micro-optimization that makes the code harder to maintain (Search for #XYZ and #XXYYZZ .... )

Answer (score 1):

You can only shorten CSS colour codes to a 3 character version if they take the form

```
#XXYYZZ
```

Then they can be abbreviated

```
#XYZ
```

There are only 216 different codes which meet this requirement.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Comment: I think it was. Earlier readers thought it was correct, too. Andrea Zilio's answer is much the same, although he expressed it in more words than I did.

Comment: Andrew updated his answer to give an actual method of accomplishing the problem.

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: Look again. The edits are just a few characters.

Comment: I agree Andrea Zilio's answer is much more comprehensive and deserves to be approved, but it's also interesting that the question was edited to use my terminology. I can tell myself it's a *moral* victory, anyway.